# Resource File Doesnt Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, multilingual

I use ASP.NET MVC5. I try to use two resource file for my MVC project. But my app doesn't get english text from resource file. It take my default res file's text. My resource files under properties folder. 
What can i do? Thanks alot.

Default res file . /properties/Resources.resx
English res file . /properties/Resources.en.resx

```
culture = "en-US";
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Comment: Can you please give code example on what exactly are you trying to accomplish? what are the Resource files for? for data annotations messages?

Comment: Can you try by renaming your Resource file - `Resources.en-US.resx`?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: My project is a multi lang web site. I've tried Resources.en-US.resx but it doesn't work. i post my code as new comment. can you look at?

Comment: where did you place your resource file? What is the Custom tool you are using? Can you check this - http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx and see if that applies to you solution.

Comment: thanks alot  ramiramilu. I've solved my problem. i my english res file's build action was wrong. i change it to "embedded resource" my problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    string culture = "tr-TR";

    if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] != null)
    {
        switch (requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString())
        {
            case "en":
                culture = "en-US";
                break;

        }
    }

    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
}
```